# Issue with 3 line text next to a div

Tags: html, css

So basically, I want to have 3 lines of text next to a `<div>`, like this (photoshop mockup):

[image]

This is my structure so far:

```css
.gd-content .gd-c-match.in-match .gd-c-match-tutorial {
    margin-top: -5px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 99px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.66);
    padding-top: 24px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}
.gd-content .gd-c-match.in-match .gd-c-match-tutorial .gd-c-tutorial-section {
    height: 57px;
    width: 290px;
    text-align: left;
}
.gd-content .gd-c-match.in-match .gd-c-match-tutorial .gd-c-tutorial-section .title {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.gd-content .gd-c-match.in-match .gd-c-match-tutorial .gd-c-tutorial-section .title .subtitle {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #494949;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.gd-content .gd-c-match.in-match .gd-c-match-tutorial .gd-c-tutorial-section .gd-c-tutorial-square {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 19px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    line-height: 17px;
    font-family: 'Uni Sans';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 57px;
    background-image: url('../../img/gd_content_match_tutorial_square.png');
}
```

```html
       <div class="gd-content">         
          <div class="gd-c-match in-match">
            <div class="gd-c-match-tutorial">
                <div class="gd-c-tutorial-section">
                    <div class="gd-c-tutorial-square">1</div><span class="title">Contact Opponent
                        <span class="subtitle">Add the other player</span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

And it works... for 2 lines.

[image]

But as soon as I get a linebreak (because of the text being too long - which is supposed to happen) it just breaks the whole thing:

[image]

Any suggestions on what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the width of `.title` to 70%

```
.gd-content .gd-c-match.in-match .gd-c-match-tutorial .gd-c-tutorial-section .title {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    width:70%;
}
```

Hope this helps..Tested by me..

```css
.gd-content .gd-c-match.in-match .gd-c-match-tutorial {
    margin-top: -5px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 99px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.66);
    padding-top: 24px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}
.gd-content .gd-c-match.in-match .gd-c-match-tutorial .gd-c-tutorial-section {
    height: 57px;
    width: 290px;
    text-align: left;
}
.gd-content .gd-c-match.in-match .gd-c-match-tutorial .gd-c-tutorial-section .title {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    width:70%;
}
.gd-content .gd-c-match.in-match .gd-c-match-tutorial .gd-c-tutorial-section .title .subtitle {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #494949;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.gd-content .gd-c-match.in-match .gd-c-match-tutorial .gd-c-tutorial-section .gd-c-tutorial-square {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 19px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    line-height: 17px;
    font-family: 'Uni Sans';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 57px;
    background-image: url('../../img/gd_content_match_tutorial_square.png');
}
```

```html
       <div class="gd-content">         
          <div class="gd-c-match in-match">
            <div class="gd-c-match-tutorial">
                <div class="gd-c-tutorial-section">
                    <div class="gd-c-tutorial-square">1</div><span class="title">Contact Opponent
                        <span class="subtitle">Add the other player ingame and form a party</span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Works so far, the problem is now that the 1 is on the bottom (it should be centered in the middle), which isn't fixable with margin top or bottom

Comment: check it again..i have updated the code...i have added the `float:left` to `.gd-c-tutorial-square`